# SCSS build scripts

Tags: css, sass, package.json

I have problem with perfix:css.I'm not a lot recognized with scss build process, if someone know what's the problem is please help me.

```
 "watch:sass": "node-sass src/styles/global.scss src/assets/css/style.css -w",
        "compile:sass": "node-sass src/styles/global.scss src/assets/css/style.comp.css",
        "prefix:css": "postcss --use autoprefixer -b 'last 10 versions' src/assets/css/style.comp.css -o src/assets/css/style.prefix.css",
        "compress:css": "node-sass src/assets/css/style.prefix.css src/assetscss/style.css --output-style compressed",
        "build:css": "npm-run-all compile:sass prefix:css compress:css"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Script on Windows

```
 "prefix:css": "postcss --use autoprefixer -b \"last 5 versions\" src/assets/css/style.comp.css -o src/assets/css/style.prefix.css"
```